# Multiplayer game with Cocos2d-Javascript and Node.js

Tags: javascript, sockets, node.js, cocos2d-iphone, multiplayer

It is possible to make a multiplayer browser based game using cocos2d-javascript + node.js? If so, is there any tutorial about that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is more suitable for this stack site in my opinion
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didin't know that, thanks! Is there a way to move the question?

Comment: Yep, there is, a moderator has the ability to do so, however you must have an active account over there I think.. Good luck